# VMWare IIS access local host from another computer

Tags: windows, iis, localhost, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a vm using windows 7 and Nat. The machine that is hosting the vmware has an ip of 19x.xxx.1.x and vm has 19x.xxx.30.xxx I am able to access iis localhost using http address from main machine to vm but I cannot access from a different 'physical' computer the localhost on the vm.

Example: main computerA has vm localhost so vmcomputer A.1 I can access A to A.1 
but a whole different computerB I can't access computerA.1

I thought I could access the vm since its on the same network but it looks like the vm is not on the same network.  Has anyone encounter this issue? Any suggestions gladly welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check ip in `computer A`

```
CMD -> Ping IpAddress In Local Host
```

Second `Firewall` Off In Computer A.

I hope this solution solved your problem.

Comment: computer A has vm installed A.1 I can access A to A.1 with http. but If I have a "friends computer" computerB can't access A.1.

Comment: firewall off computer A?

Comment: check ip recived data for computer A.

Comment: check your connectivity.

Comment: Your LAN is not connect Computer A And Computer B

Comment: computer A and B on wifi same network but vmware has computerA.1 as Lan.

Comment: all Compter use Same Router?

Comment: problem your LAN and wifi Connectivity.

Comment: Ping from ComputerA to computerA.1 is fine now. But still can't access computerA.1 from computer B.

Comment: All Compter Are LAN trough connect?

Comment: No, only wifi same router. Firewall on both computerA and A.1 off. still nothing from computerB to A.1

Comment: why not use same router All Compter?

Comment: Yes all are on the same router connected through wifi

Comment: Hooray We fix it! You were right it was the router! Thank you so much Denish Parvadia!